# file locked after youtube resumable upload java sdk

Tags: java, youtube-api

My java code did direct upload of a video and afterwards the program can move the file to a folder.

I have just change the code to do resumable upload but now after the upload the file cannot be moved. I can see, at least with jdk 7 on windows "Files.move", "file is being used by another process" -- (not exact message but similar).  Also on mac lion with jdk6 I can confirm that file move does not work anymore but I cannot see error message because Files.move is available on jdk7 apparently.

I tried closing the file like this.

```
ms.getInputFileStream().close();
```

as well as this

```
new FileInputStream(ms.getMedaiFile()).close()
```

But no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

The resumable code is essentially what is in the youtube api example/demo package.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code in order to test this scenario? Maybe you can solve this problem in Java 7 with "try-with-resource".

See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue190.html

Comment: I solve this problem by copying the video to a temporary file and then uploading this temporary.  Not that, before this fix, the problem was isolated on windows only.  I develop on both windows and mac and since mac has only java 6 I prefer not to rely on java 7